# Why is that integral written as the product of 2 other integrals?

Tags: partial-fractions

I am a student and just learning about integrals. **Could you please explain to me how the highlighted part of the equation was derived?**
 I can't quite understand how was the c/a term brought of the integral and how 1 integral just became a product of 2 other ones.
Thank you in advance!

---

[image]

---

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely use it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no product of two integrals there. What the author is claiming is that, since we always have$$\frac{cx+d}{ax+b}=\frac ca+\frac{d-\frac{bc}a}{ax+b},$$then$$\int\frac{cx+d}{ax+b}\,\mathrm dx$$is the **sum** of$$\int\frac ca\,\mathrm dx\quad\text{with}\quad\int\frac{d-\frac{bc}a}{ax+b}\,\mathrm dx.$$That is, it is the sum of$$\frac ca\int\mathrm dx\quad\text{with}\quad\left(d-\frac{bc}a\right)\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{ax+b}.$$

Comment: Yeah... Thanks a lot. That notaion used in a book was a little confusing to me, but now I get it.

Comment: You left $\frac{c}{a}$ in the second Integral

Comment: @jjagmath I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our quality standard policy. Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.